# how to use Django Hitcount in a function based view rather than a class?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

The documentation covered only the usage of Django-Hitcount in a class-based view.

```
from hitcount.views import HitCountDetailView

class PostCountHitDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
    model = Post        # your model goes here
    count_hit = True    # set to True if you want it to try and count the hit
```

Is there any way to use it in a function?

Comment: You can implement the logic that the `HitCountDetailView` implements yes: https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/blob/develop/hitcount/views.py#L150-L164

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, you only need to implement the logic that the [`HitCountDetailView` implements [GitHub]](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/blob/1.3.3/hitcount/views.py#L149-L164).

So for a function-based view that "hits" an object of *`MyModel`* this looks like:

```
from hitcount.utils import get_hitcount_model
from hitcount.views import HitCountMixin

def some_view(request, pk):
    object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=pk)
    context = {}

    # hitcount logic
    hit_count = get_hitcount_model().objects.get_for_object(object)
    hits = hit_count.hits
    hitcontext = context['hitcount'] = {'pk': hit_count.pk}
    hit_count_response = HitCountMixin.hit_count(request, hit_count)
    if hit_count_response.hit_counted:
        hits = hits + 1
        hitcontext['hit_counted'] = hit_count_response.hit_counted
        hitcontext['hit_message'] = hit_count_response.hit_message
        hitcontext['total_hits'] = hits

    # … extra logic …

    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

This however to some extent illustrates that a class-based view is more suited for such tasks: one can easily define the logic in *reusable* components, and thus mix it in the existing logic.

Comment: It counts once for every IP. I want it count every hit. Please how I achieve that. What do I need to overwrite?

Comment: The answer is a bit late, as a simple solution you can see the number of hits in your admin panel with hitcount.